# Sum Values From Different Columns

Tags: php, sum

I am having problem adding up the values in a column with php.
These values where sent from checkboxes and i want to count only the values that where checked from the unit column.
Here is my code:

```
<?php
$id = $_POST['course'];
foreach($id as $value)
{
    //echo $value; 
    $query = " SELECT * FROM french  WHERE id= $value ";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed');
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))  {  
    $id = $row['id'];
    $course = htmlspecialchars($row['course_name']);
    $code = htmlspecialchars($row['course_code']);
    $unit = $row['unit'];
    $status = $row['status'];
?>
```

Comment: You don't mention what is wrong with your code..

Comment: this is the code am trying to use to sum:

Comment: So, where are you using the `SUM`?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is an error when you copied your code into this post, but you seem to have left out the closing brackets for both of the loops.

Comment: it was an error while posting

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying like this? Getting form array of form checkboxs and checking on database via ID's?

HTML FORM

```
Check 1 <input type="checkbox" name="val[]" />
Check 2 <input type="checkbox" name="val[]" />
```

PHP RESULT

```
$val = $_POST['val'];
$count = count($val);
foreach ($val as $val_res)
{
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM french WHERE id='.$val_res;
}
```

Comment: No. am designing a student E-Portal. During course registration the student is to select the course he want to register. what i want to do is to sum the unit of each course e.g math 2, eng 3 = 5.